# Angular 7 HttpClient response type as class

Tags: httpclient, getter-setter, angular7, typechecking

I am trying to cast my response from a http get call using httpclient and create an instance of a class I have created.

**PROBLEM**
The HttpClient doesnt seem to create a new instance of my class using the properties of its response object. Please help!

I have tried creating a class vs interface. Not sure what else i need to be doing here.

**My Class**

```
export class Escalation {    
  constructor(private NAME: string, private DESCRIPTION: string) { }    

  public get name() {    
    return this.NAME;    
  }

  public set name(name: string) {    
    this.NAME = name;    
  }

  public get description() {    
    return this.DESCRIPTION;    
  }

  public set description(description: string) {    
    this.DESCRIPTION = description;    
  }    
}
```

**My Service**

```
public getEscalation(escalationName) {    
    return this.http.get(`${this.globals.baseRestUrl}/companies/escalations/${escalationName}`);    
  }
```

**My Component**

```
public escalation: Escalation = new Escalation('', '');    

this.companiesService.getEscalation(escalationName).subscribe(    
        (escalationResponse: Escalation) => this.escalation = {    
          ...escalationResponse    
        }, (error: any) => {       
          console.log(error);   
        }    
      );
```

**Expected Result**
I was expecting my response to be casted to type Escalation (My class) upon api callback.

**Actual Result**
the api returns an object like so:

```
{    
    NAME: 'Escalation 1',    
    DESCRIPTION: 'This is a test description'    
}
```

But eventually this.escalation returns undefined

I hope I explained it well. Please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: When does `this.companiesService.getEscalation(...)` get called?

Comment: This gets called in my custom component’s Oninit method @Mitch Wilkins

Comment: So when you log this.escalation to the console you get undefined but the API returns the desired result?

Comment: The API returns the json response, but i would like to cast that to my custom Escalation class which is not happening if that makes sense. @Mitch Wilkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(escalationResponse: Escalation)` line of code isn't really intended to *cast* the response from the HttpClient but rather to **infer** what type it is.

You may consider adjusting your code to `this.escalation = new Escalation(escalationResponse.NAME, escalationResponse.DESCRIPTION)`

I believe `this.escalation = { ...escalationResponse }` is really only deconstructing the properties anyway.